# unable to open Berkeley db /etc/sasldb2: No such file or directory

Tags: postfix, sasl, smtpd

In /var/log/mail.log I get such error message:

```
Jul 25 01:33:11 ubuntu8 postfix/smtpd[10863]: warning: SASL authentication problem: unable to open Berkeley db /etc/sasldb2: No such file or directory
```

But the database is here:

```
# ls -l /etc/sasldb2
-r--r----- 1 postfix sasl 12288 2010-07-25 01:29 /etc/sasldb2
```

How can I fix/diagnose that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your smtpd chrooted?  Check Postfix's master.cf for 'y' or '-' in the fifth column for the smtpd service.

Comment: Indeed, it is chrooted, I see '-'.

Comment: I moved the sasldb into the jail 'mv /etc/sasldb2 /var/spool/postfix/etc' and now it works. Thank you!